# Adding wrapping tags before and after a specified tag

Tags: jquery

I've recently started a course on jQuery and wondered what's going wrong with my code. I want to add an opening li before each "wcprow" div and closing the li after the closing div... So it looks like:

```
<li>
<div class="wcprow">
    Content
</div>
</li>
```

My current HTML is

```
<ul>

<div class="wcprow">
    Content
</div>

<div class="wcprow">
    Content
</div>

<div class="wcprow">
    Content
</div>

</ul>
```

And jQuery:

```
$('.wcprow').before("<li>"); $('.wcprow').after("</li>");
```

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/7313ezjh/)

When I view via dev tools, it outputs a closing li directly after the opening one. Which is not what I want.

```
<li></li><div class="wcprow">
    Content
</div>
```

I'm at the start of this course and might stumble on the answer later on... But wondered if anyone can give me any pointers so I'm not thinking about it too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misinterpreting how `.before()` and `.after()` work. If you call it like you did:

```
$('.wcprow').before('<li>');
```

It will create a new element (think `document.createElement('li')`) and it will insert this complete node right before `.wcprow`. It will not just insert an opening or closing tag. It's the same as:

```
let e = document.createElement('li');
$('.wcprow').before(e);
```

What you want to do is to wrap an element in another. So you're looking for `.wrap()`:

> Wrap an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements.

It's as simple as this:

```
$('.wcprow').wrap('<li></li>');
```

**Further Reading**

- [jQuery .wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)
- [jQuery .before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/)
- [jQuery .after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

**Demo**

[Try before buy](https://jsfiddle.net/nqb5z19e/)

**Note**

You start with invalid HTML. A `div` cannot be a child of an `ul|ol`-element. Even though you're going to "repair" this by wrapping the container in `li`-elements later, your code should be intact from the beginning.